# Apk signature changed after visual studio update

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova

yesterday I've updated visual studio 2017 to the last version and now I've got a problem with a cordova android app because now the apk that visual studio generates seems to have a different signature so I keep getting this error and can't update my app

> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Packag signatures do not match
>   the previously installed version; ignoring!]

any help?
thanks

Comment: It's not possibile. Maybe you try to install a Debug version over a Release one which was generated by "Generate signed APK" menu.

Comment: I've installed always the debug version but from this morning somehow it has a different signature

Comment: You can open the APK using a Zip/7Zip utility and check "META-INF/xxxx.RSA" and "META-INF/xxxxxxx.SF" files content using a simple TextEditor like Notepad. Search for differences.